# Wordpress - Get User's image ID from Pods field

Tags: php, wordpress, image, podscms

I am currently working with the Pods plugin.

I extended the user pod and I added a corporate image field.

On the administration everything is fine, I can change the image of each user.

[image]
AND :

[image]

My problem is that I can not display this image on a front office page..

If i do this : `var_dump($pod->field('image_societe'));`
It return false, while the field name is correct, and for plain text fields, it works.

But i can do this :

```
var_dump($pod->fields('image_societe'));
```

This will return me full of information, but I do not have access to the id of the image, it is not present in the information.

I would like to finally be able to do this:

```
the_attachment_link( 11923 );
```

Where 11923 is the image's ID.

To be dynamic according to the user, the documentation says that it must be done like this:

```
the_attachment_link($pod->field('image_societe.ID'));
```

But as pods return me false, it does not work.

Does someone have an idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can get the image url by querying `$pod->field('image_societe.guid')`. E.g. :

```
$items = pods('your_pod', array("limit" => -1));
while($items->fetch()) {
    echo $items->field('image_societe.guid');
}
```

If `$pod->field('image_societe');` doesn't return anything, then something might be wrong with your pod query, or caching kicking in. So more code would be needed to review this.